# Error: Control may reach end of non-void function, Xcode

Tags: c

I know there are many questions and answers about my problem,

but those don't help because there are different situations.

This is my code.

```
BinNode *Search(BinNode *p, const Member *x)
{
    int cond;
    if(p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if((cond = MemberNoCmp(x, &p->data)) == 0)
        return p;
    else if(cond < 0)
        Search(p->left, x);
    else
        Search(p->right, x);
}
```

and the error message.

> Control may reach end of non-void function

I think my function is going to execute well, and I think this is an important line.

```
if(p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if((cond = MemberNoCmp(x, &p->data)) == 0)
        return p;
```

I think this will eventually return NULL or p unconditionally.

What is the problem I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a "non-`void`" function you *must* return something on every branch that might be taken. In other words:

```
BinNode *Search(BinNode *p, const Member *x)
{
    int cond;
    if(p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if((cond = MemberNoCmp(x, &p->data)) == 0)
        return p;
    else if(cond < 0)
        return Search(p->left, x);
    else
        return Search(p->right, x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really simple, and I think I should think a little bit. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't worry, C has a lot of sharp edges and using a compiler like Xcode with a lot of warnings enabled by default helps protect you from hours of confusion later. If you didn't fix this and it compiled anyway, which it could if you turn off all warnings and error checks, you'd end up getting junk data back by mistake and your program would act very strangely.